# unable to display multiple selected values in edit blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to display multiple selected values in my blade file however none of the values that should be selected are and I'm not sure why.

***controller***

```
public function getEdit($productId)
{
    $country_id = $product->region_country_id;
    $regions = Region::where("country_id",$country_id)
                    ->where("activation",1)->get();  
    $countries = Country::getActiveCountry();

    return View::make('product.edit', 
                        [
                            'regions' => $regions,
                            'countries' => $countries,
                        ]
                      );
}
```

***view***

```
 <div class="col-lg-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="region_country_id" name="region_country_id[]" multiple style="height: 10%">
        {{$selected = explode(",",$product->region_country_id);}}
  <?php foreach ($countries as $key => $value) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value->id; ?>" <?php  in_array($value->id,$selected) ? 'selected' : ''  ?>><?php echo $value->name;?></option>
  <?php } 
  ?>


    </select>
    <select class="form-control" id="region_id" name="region_id[]" style="margin-top: 10px;height: 10%" multiple>
         {{$selected = explode(",",$product->region_id);}}
<?php if(Session::get('branch_access') != 1){?>
            <option value="">All region</option>
<?php } ?>
<?php foreach ($regions as $key => $value)  { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value->id; ?>" <?php  in_array($value->id,$selected) ? 'selected' : ''  ?>><?php echo $value->region; ?></option>
<?php  } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing an extra = in your if statement. `!==` instead of `!=`.

Also, there is no syntax for declaring a variable inside of a blade template and it is discouraged to do so. `{{ $stuff }}` is syntax for echoing.

In your controller you should declare variables for `$selected` and build the view with them.

Here's a more proper version of your template using blade syntax.

```
<select class="form-control" id="region_country_id" name="region_country_id[]" multiple style="height: 10%">
    @foreach($countries as $country)
    <option value="{{$country->id}}" {{ in_array($country->id, $cselected) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{$country->name}}
    </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="region_id" name="region_id[]" style="margin-top: 10px;height: 10%" multiple>
    <option value="">All region</option>

    @if(session()->get('branch_access') !== 1))
        @foreach($regions as $region)
        <option value="{{$region->id}}" {{ in_array($region->id, $rselected) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            {{$region->region}}
        </option>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</select>
```

And your controller:

```
<?php
public function getEdit($productId) {
   $country_id = $product->region_country_id;
   $regions = Region::where([
       ['country_id', ,'=', $country_id],
       ['activation', '=', 1]
    ])->get();  
   $countries = Country::getActiveCountry();

    return view('product.edit', [
        'regions' => $regions,
        'countries' => $countries,
        'cselected' => explode(',', $product->region_country_id),
        'rselected' => explode(',', $product->region_id),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: but am not getting regions

Comment: @gauthamg updated. Please read the answer & try to fix things on your own.